# Implement custom Postgres index as extension

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, indexing

I was wondering if it is possible to implement a custom index as a postgres extension? I tried to find an answer via Google, but was not very successful (mainly because of the ambiguity of the search query).

Maybe someone has already implemented a custom index and can point me to some literature or code.

Comment: You mean beyond the [predefined index types]( https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-types.html)? Yes, there's an API to extend these it seems: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xindex.html

Comment: Some of these https://www.postgresql.org/download/products/6-postgresql-extensions/ seem to work with indexes, maybe one of those is a good example?

Answer (score 5):

According to [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexam.html):

> The core system knows nothing about indexes beyond what is specified here, so it is possible to develop entirely new index types by writing add-on code.

To add a new index method, you create a new *index access method*.

An example of that is available as the “contrib” module [bloom](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/bloom.html), which implements Bloom filters as a PostgreSQL index type. The source code of that module will server as guidance how to create your own index access method.